# Why is my new workflow being ignored?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

I've updated an existing workflow created in SharePoint Designer.  I've removed the old instances from Settings -> List Settings -> Workflow Settings -> Remove a workflow, and recompiled.  The OLD workflow is somehow still running and ignoring my NEW workflow.
I've tried deleting the ASPX pages from SharePoint Designer and recompiling and that did not fix it.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Does your workflow run when new items are added to a list or Document library? If so you may need to restart the OWSTIMER.EXE service (Windows SharePoint Services Timer). When I had this problem I also added a version number to the workflow logs to make it easier to track when SharePoint was using the older code. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a workflow that was in progress when you removed and recompiled the workflow? If so, that is expected behaviour, those workflows will complete with the old version, and only new instances from the latest build of the workflow will run with the new code.